# Funny behaviour of wordpress 3.9.1. menu

Tags: css, wordpress

Please see http://alltimeplay.com/

The menu has funny behaviour while clicking. The page screen also shifts. It floats to left or right. When clicked in same position the screen occupies the normal position. Could not navigate to the pages.

I could not figure out why.

Any help?

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: I am using latest version of firefox

Comment: Same behaviour in IE 8 also.

Comment: Small note: you have `<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]><!-->` for your `<html>` tag. You probably mean `if !((IE 7) | (IE 8))` or `if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)`. Otherwise, you may get two `<html> tags on IE7/8 because they both technically match the expression you currently have.

Comment: I see the same behavior in firefox. It has something to do with class 'focus' getting added to <html>, <body> and <header>. Check you js

Comment: Currently I have not added any js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably lies with a "focus" class being added *all the way up the DOM tree*. I do not see it being added like that in Chrome, but it is happening in IE11.

In functions.js, line 100: http://alltimeplay.com/wp-content/themes/ATP/js/functions.js?ver=20140319

```
// Focus styles for menus.
    $( '.primary-navigation, .secondary-navigation' ).find( 'a' ).on( 'focus.twentyfourteen blur.twentyfourteen', function() {
        $( this ).parents().toggleClass( 'focus' );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my css I have class .focus  I renamed it and now it is ok.

Comment: Welcome! Don't forget to accept if it is the correct answer.